# How to solve memory leak in window form

Tags: c#, memory

My problem is that memory is increased 5MB flicker form each time a call per second .

I made window flicker effect window form

[flicker form]

```
 public partial class WarningBoxControls : Form
    {
        bool _isShadow;
        public WarningBoxControls(WarningBoxType _Type)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += WarningBox_FormClosing;
            this.VisibleChanged +=WarningBoxControls_VisibleChanged;
            if (_Type == WarningBoxType.WarningBox_Speed)
            {
                MessageTitle.Text = "속력 경고";
                MessageContent.Text = "자동차 속도를 줄여주세요!";
                this.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.warning_speed;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageTitle.Text = "Logger 오류";
                MessageContent.Text = "Logger가 활성화되지 않았습니다!";
                this.BackColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.warning_error;
            }

        }

        private void WarningBoxControls_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0.01;
            if(this.Visible == true)
            {
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
        private void WarningBox_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
                pictureBox1.Dispose();
            }
            if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isShadow == false)
            {
                if (this.Opacity <= 1.0)
                {
                    this.Opacity += 0.8;
                    if (this.Opacity >= 1.0)
                    {
                        _isShadow = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.Opacity >= 0.01)
                {
                    this.Opacity -= 0.08;
                    if (this.Opacity <= 0.01)
                    {
                        _isShadow = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I created the class to load flicker effect form.

[load ficker form]

```
public class WarningBox
    {
        WarningBoxControls _control;
        Form owner;

        public WarningBox(IWin32Window _owner, WarningBoxType _Type)
        {
            if (_owner != null)
            {
                owner = (Form)_owner;

                _control = new WarningBoxControls(_Type);
                _control.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                _control.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                _control.ControlBox = false;
                _control.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                _control.Size = new Size(owner.Size.Width - 40, _control.Height - 20);


            }
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            _control.Location = new Point(owner.Location.X + 20, owner.Location.Y + ((owner.Height - _control.Height) / 2));
            //_control.ShowDialog();
            //_control.BringToFront();

            if(_control.Visible != true)
            {
                _control.Show();
                _control.BringToFront();
            }


        }
        public void Hide()
        {
            if(_control.Visible != false)
            {
                //_control.Visible = false;
                _control.Hide();

            }

        }
        ~WarningBox()
        {
            if(_control != null)
            {
                _control.Dispose();
                _control = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Call a second method]

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                ReadLoggerStatus();

            }

    private void ReadLoggerStatus()
            {
                if (_Lights != null)
                {
                    if (_Lights.ERR == 0) // 에러 없을때
                    {
                        pb_error.Image = Properties.Resources.none;
                        _WarningBox.Hide();
                        btn_stop.Enabled = true;
                        btn_start.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        pb_error.Image = Properties.Resources.error;
                        _WarningBox.Show();
                        btn_stop.Enabled = false;
                        btn_start.Enabled = true;

                    }
                }
            }
```

And Check the one error per second , call the `Show()` and `Hide()` of `WarningBox`. however here(`ReadLoggerStatus()`) is some of a problem.

my problem is that  the memory each time it is called once per second increased by 5MB.

I want to know it is solve the best way.

please let me know excellent answer.

In advance, I would greetings of thanks.

Have a good day!

Comment: Don't know if it applies here, but I've heard of cases where GDI+ images caused memory problems when reloaded. Haven't looked at the rest of the code, but you could try caching the images (`Properties.Resources.error` and `...none` ) outside the ReadLoggerStatus procedure (or for a quick test, exclude the image set lines)